# Systems of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> Find non-negative solutions of systems of equations:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x^2y^2+1=x^2+xy
> \\
> y^2z^2+1=y^2+yz
> \\
> z^2x^2+1=z^2+zx
> \end{cases}
> $$

**My work so far:**

1) $(1;1;1) - $ solution.

2) $(y^2-1)x^2-yx+1=0$

$D=y^2-4(y^2-1)=-3y^2+4\ge0 \Rightarrow 0\le y \le \frac2{\sqrt3}$

3) $x^2y^2+1-(y^2z^2+1)=x^2+xy-(y^2+yz)$

$y^2(x-z)(x+z)=(x-y)(x+y)+y(x-z)$

Comment: As well, $(x, y, z) = (-1,-1,-1)$. Can you assume symmetry and take $x = y = z$? That gives $x, = \pm 1$ (assuming $x$ is real). What about then just assuming $x=y$? This then gives $x, y$ = $\pm 1,\pm 1$ and $z = 0$ (and similarly for $x = z$ etc. Three *linear* equations in three unknowns has a solution (assuming consistency), but do three *non-linear* equations necessarily have a solution?

Comment: @jim Just because a system is symmetric does not mean it's solution has to be when all or some of its variables are equal. At best you can conclude any solution implies its permutations are also solutions. Can you prove what you're saying?

Comment: I did say *can you assume*, I was wondering where the systems of equations came from.

Comment: (ignore the comments about $x=1, y=1, z=0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $y=hx$. Then the first equation gives $h^2x^4-(h+1)x^2+1=0$. Hence $(h+1)^2\ge (2h)^2$, so $h\le 1$. Similarly, putting $z=ky$ we get $k\le 1$ from the second equation. But then $x=\frac{1}{hk}z$ and the third equation gives $hk\ge1$, so we must have $x=y=z$. Now the first equation gives $x^4-2x^2+1=0$ so $x^2=1$ and hence $x=1$. So the unique solution is $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: Very nice use of symmetry! +1

Comment: $x^2 = 1$ gives $x = \pm 1$

Comment: @jim But we are told to find non-negative solutions.

Comment: ooops, silly of me